# Obtain other 'objects/records' as property of another 'column/attribute'

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have 3 tables:

Item and `OwnerImage` have Foreign Key to `Owner`. Not all `Owner` have `Item`(s)

```
Item

id  name    owner_id (fk)
1   alpha   1
2   beta    1


Owner

id name
1   owner1
2   owner2

OwnerImage

id  name    owner_id (fk)
1   image1   1
2   image2   1
```

I want to get a list of all Items, and their Owner and OwnerImage, which I can do with a join.

But it is possible, to get the Owner as a 'property' of Item from database:

Item.Owner.OwnerImage (like an object)

At this moment I'm doing 3 queries and do the matching using `loops` in code(python), but I want to know if it is possible with one query;

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Like I said, I query them separatelly at this moment, and do a match in python, by looping and check if the fk and primary_keys are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join` to select data for a given value in another table where a relationship exists:

```
select owner
from owner o1
inner join ownerimage o2
on o2.owner_id = o1.id
```

Not sure how `EVENT` ties into this, but this should get you started

Comment: my mistake, I wrote Event instead of Item, thanks I updated